# How to access Kivy screens manager.<property> using Python

Tags: android, python, screen, kivy

Background: I have been learning Python - and through it - Kivy, by making an app. I have been using the .kv file and Builder.load_string methods to create my graphics, but have decided to try using solely python, and moving all of my layouts over into python.

The Problem: When I began using screens, I was unable to bind the correct code to the buttons to make the screens transition. When I am writing the line, 'self.manager.etc...' auto-complete shows me a list of valid properties to use.

So after 'self.' it shows that I can use 'manager', and after 'manager.' it does not think that the screen's manager has a 'current' or 'transition' property. I must have messed up in how I connected the screen to the manager, but I cannot fathom how.

```
class HomePage(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HomePage, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        layout = FloatLayout()

        notification = Label(text='upcoming: ....', font_size='16sp', size_hint=(0,0), pos_hint={'center_x':.5, 'top':0.9})
        layout.add_widget(notification)

        button_row=BoxLayout(size_hint_y=.1, spacing=20)

        profile_button=Label(text='Profile')
        button_row.add_widget(profile_button)

        layout.add_widget(button_row)
        self.add_widget(layout)

        def transit():
            self.manager.current = profile_button # <- this should work, right?

        profile_button.bind(on_press=transit)

class ScreenApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(HomePage(name='home'))
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ScreenApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add in your imports the transition

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, FadeTransition
```

And pass it in the builder

```
class ScreenApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager(transition=FadeTransition())
```

as for the current you should add a second screen, give it a name and and use that name to change to that screen.from the https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/screenmanager.py

> by default, the first added screen will be shown. If you want to
>   show another one, just set the 'current' property. sm.current = 'second'

Also current is a string property, you can not set it to a label

> :attr:`current` is a :class:`~kivy.properties.StringProperty` and
>   defaults to None.

So your full code should be something like

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, FadeTransition


class HomePage(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HomePage, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        layout = FloatLayout()

        notification = Label(text='upcoming: ....', font_size='16sp', size_hint=(0,0), pos_hint={'center_x':.5, 'top':0.9})
        layout.add_widget(notification)

        button_row=BoxLayout(size_hint_y=.1, spacing=20)

        profile_button=Button(text='Profile') # changed to a button
        button_row.add_widget(profile_button)
        profile_button.bind(on_press=self.transit) # moved here the bind action
        layout.add_widget(button_row)
        self.add_widget(layout)

    def transit(self, *args):
        # unintended to become a class method and reference to it with self
        print "ok"
        self.manager.current = "screen2"


class ProfilePage(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ProfilePage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        layout = FloatLayout()
        labelP = Label(text="Profile Page")
        layout.add_widget(labelP)
        self.add_widget(layout)




class ScreenApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager(transition=FadeTransition())
        # create the first screen
        screen1 = HomePage(name='Home') #your home page
        screen2 = ProfilePage(name='screen2') # the second screen
        sm.add_widget(screen1)
        sm.add_widget(screen2)
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ScreenApp().run()
```

Comment: Ok, I was able to get it working with a few modifications from what you have here. New question / problem, but along the same lines. manager does not have a .transition property so when I use SlideTransition it only slides one way for every transition. I know it has a '.transition' property, but once again, my compiler thinks that it does not exist.

Comment: I could not bind the profile_button above the transit method declaration because the compiler thought transit didn't exist at that point. And lastly, passing transit self, when bound to the button passed the button instead of the screen. so removing the self and just using def transit(*args) worked like a charm.

Comment: EDIT: nevermind, I got access to the transition property finally!